# Google Bigtable - how to store data to be able then to query it by country, city and date?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I'm looking for a best scheme for my Bigtable to fit the requirement of querying data by specifying a year (or full date), country and (or) city. I've thought about naming my row key as `2019.us.NYC` and then query it by prefixes, but its a bad idea because its then will store all my data on one node only until 2020 year comes instead of sharing it to other nodes. Any ideas? Maybe someone already had such a case? The bottleneck here is that it will have about 50 000 000 new rows per second.

Edit: Maybe it's better to use BigQuery?

Comment: To answer your last question, BigQuery have quotas on streaming inserts (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) : 100'000 rows per second per project, so Bigtable is probably the database you want to use. Could you please clarify your data querying requirements? In your question, are these exclusive *or*, or can you query on both full date and country for example? Do you need low latency for data access? Please also include a sample of data you want to store to help you design your Bigtable schema.

Comment: @norbjd Thanks for your help, first of all. The requirement is to be able to query data by specifieng at least year and country. Additionaly can be speciafied mounth, day and city name. Low latency is very important. I plan to store simple json value that contains everything I need, but it's will be much better if I'll be able to store the data directly to the table families.

Comment: @norbjd In MySQL table this query would look something like this: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE country = 'us' AND city = 'new_york' AND date = '2019-08-12' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100` or: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE country = 'de' AND city = 'berlin' AND YEAR(date) = '2017' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100`

Comment: BigTable forces a single key. You want to have a combined key with another value on the end. So maybe something like '2019.us.Nyc.{guid}' where guid is some unique identifier you create per value. You then can use a simple range operator that should be able to be nearly as fast as possible if your wanting the entire group.Then you could do between '2019.us.nyc.{empty-guid}' and '2019.us.nyc.{max-guid}' to find all the data while still having unique rows.

Look at range filters
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable

Comment: To answer to the above comment, using `2019.us.Nyc.{guid}` as a rowkey will lead to Bigtable node hotspotting (consecutive writes on a same node), because the row keys will be contiguous, as @Mmh1 correctly understood and wrote in his question. Moreover, querying the data from Bigquery to access Bigtable data is probably not the solution if low latency reads are required.

Comment: @norbjd how much "low latency" is actually is? 1-3 seconds is OK for my case, I think. But its will grow very fast, so I'm afraid its need something complex.

Comment: I don't know about Bigquery on Bigtable, but the Bigquery overhead is probably greater than 1 second. Anyway, your row key needs to be designed correctly. Scans (between known start keys and end keys) is the most performant way to access the data. That's why the beginning of the row key is so important. You could then benchmark if you want to query Bigtable directly or via Bigquery.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a possible solution, based on your requirements :

- 50'000'000 writes per second
- low latency for data access
- queries always contain `year` and `country`, optionally `month`, `day` and `city`

#### `year` + `country`

Since `year` and `country` are always present in your queries, those must figure in the beginning of the row key, like :

- `2018#de`
- `2019#de`
- `2019#us`

(I used `#` to delimit here, but it may be useless if `year` and `country` are always defined respectively on 4 and 2 characters. You can remove it to save a byte!).

#### `month` + `day` + `city`

Because `month`, `day` and `city` are optional, they can also appear on the row key, but rather to the end :

- `2018#de#0610#frankfurt`
- `2019#de#0115#berlin`
- `2019#us#0813#nyc`

I suggest you to reorder elements as you want (if queries with `year`, `country` and `city` are the most common, then the order should be `year#country#city`). Only you can know the most frequent queries. It's always necessary to [design your row key with your queries in mind](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#design_your_row_key_with_your_queries_in_mind).

#### Avoid hotspotting

But, as you suggested in your question, this row key design can lead to Bigtable node hotspotting (all writes to a single node because the row keys are contiguous). To solve this and ensure a perfect distribution of the row keys between your nodes, I suggest you to use bucketing.

For each write, you can generate a random number (between 0 and 8, *for example* if you want 8 buckets), and prepend that bucket number to your rowkey. For example :

- `3#2018#de#0610#frankfurt`
- `2#2019#de#0115#berlin`
- `7#2019#us#0813#nyc`

You'll then be sure that your keys will be correctly distributed across your Bigtable nodes when writing.

You can check this link on how to do this on HBase (Bigtable equivalent) : https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema.casestudies.log_timeseries.tslead.

#### Querying data

But because of this bucketing (or salting), you'll need to change the way you query your table. If you want all data for 2019 in US, you'll then need to perform 8 scans (one per bucket) :

- start key : `0#2019#us#`, end key : `0#2019#us~`
- start key : `1#2019#us#`, end key : `1#2019#us~`
- start key : `2#2019#us#`, end key : `2#2019#us~`
- start key : `3#2019#us#`, end key : `3#2019#us~`
- start key : `4#2019#us#`, end key : `4#2019#us~`
- start key : `5#2019#us#`, end key : `5#2019#us~`
- start key : `6#2019#us#`, end key : `6#2019#us~`
- start key : `7#2019#us#`, end key : `7#2019#us~`

(I used `~` at the end of the end key because `~` in the ASCII table is after all possible characters after the `#`. For the first scan, for example, this ensures that all row keys beginning by `0#2019#us#` are retrieved)

These scans can be performed in parallel for maximum performance.

Scanning is the most performant way to query data in Bigtable. You could also use some filters (like [`FuzzyRowFilter`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/com/google/cloud/bigtable/hbase/adapters/filters/FuzzyRowFilterAdapter) to query on a row key with a particular regex), but scanning will give definitively give you a better latency. You can also perform scans and use a filter after scanning (for example, to retrieve all data for `2019` in `us` in `nyc`, a filter is necessary to get only lines with `city = nyc`).

#### Conclusion

So, based on these elements, I'll design my key like :

```
<bucket_number>#<year>#<country>#<month><day>#<city>
```

to query my table **using scans**. Separators (`#` here) are useless if all fields have fixed length.

You could also have some variants without bucketing if you have a sufficient number of `<country>` values to distribute the keys to the different nodes :

```
<year>#<country>#<month><day>#<city>
```

or :

```
<country>#<year>#<month><day>#<city>
```

In conclusion, it's always a tradeoff when designing Bigtable row keys. By using bucketing, you always avoid hotspotting but the way you query the data is more complex. But, based on your requirements (many writes), this is what I'll do.

You can change the number of buckets depending on your number of nodes in your Bigtable cluster also. If you have more than 8 nodes, I recommend you to create more buckets. Ideally, 1 bucket = 1 node but a node can easily contain multiple buckets.

I suggest though to test this key design with others and benchmark them in real conditions (PoC). You could use the [Bigtable Key Visualizer](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/keyvis-overview) to check the distribution of your keys across your cluster.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to rely on filters to get a small subset of rows. Bigtable will still have to read ALL data for the range you scan and will apply the filter afterwards. This will not avoid hotspotting in the filtered-out rows.

Comment: Also, contiguous row keys will not typically lead to hotspotting of a node since Bigtable will continue to split a tablet to reduce load and shuffle tablets amongst nodes to spread load. Hotspotting will mostly happen when a single row / key is used frequently.

Comment: To answer your comment about filtering : you're right, that's why I suggested to **scan the data before**, and filter after **if needed**. But sometimes, filtering is necessary. In the example I took with the `city` : if `city` is located at the end of the key, and if we don't know what's between `country` and `city`, then the only possibility is to filter. We can't rely on scans to retrieve data related to the city, but we can scan in a first step to retrieve all data in the desired year and country.

Comment: Bucketing can indeed be avoided if there are enough `country` values to ensure that the row keys are correctly distributed. I've updated the answer accordingly. Without more precisions, bucketing is still a good idea when dealing with such a high write throughput : even if splits are performed automatically by Bigtable, this operation have a cost and avoiding them (as much as possible) is always better.

Comment: @norbjd `<country>#<year>#<month><day>#<city>` - wouldn't it result in a hotspot  if have 500 nodes and 200 countries? I can't understand how it works... The more nodes I have, the less chances to get a hotspot?

Comment: @norbjd @norbjd I think I can set 100-200 unique identifiers to each country (000 - 100 for `us`, 101-200 for `de` and so on) and then include that identifier in the row at the first place. Additionally I can add more nodes. Will it work? The row then will looks like: `000000000000123#2019#08#13#nyc` - `us`, `000000000000149#2019#08#12#berlin` - `de`

Comment: Increasing the number of nodes won't solve hotspotting if all writes target the same node anyway. Bigtable is of course able to split the data to spread load, as said in a previous comment, but based on my experience, designing your rowkey thinking about key distribution is always a good idea. Using an unique identifier instead of the country code don't solve any problem here, the distribution will be the same.